# How can I send recurring email from Perl?

Tags: perl, datetime, email

I am using the MIME::Lite to send emails from Perl to Outlook. For my application, I need to send emails periodically every Monday and Wednesday, after a certain date.

Here's the code I'm using to send the emails.

```
        my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
            From => $from,
            To   => $to,
            Subject => $subject,
            Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
        );
        $msg->attach(
            Type => 'text/html',
            Data => $mailbody,
        );
        $msg->send;
```

Also, I get the date and process it as follows. I need to send emails every Monday and wednesday from $date1 and $p3_6wk.

```
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%m-%d-%Y');
my $dt   = $strp->parse_datetime($date1);
my $p3_6wk =  $dt->add(days => 42)->strftime("%m-%d-%Y");
```

P.S : My outer script runs on a cron already and my team does not want to add another cron for the same job. So, I'm trying to figure if there's some way that avoids me having another cron for this logic.

Comment: Run the script from `cron` or whatever scheduling facility your OS provides.

Comment: This script is a part of another huge script. So I', looking only to run this particular function on a periodic basis. Not the whole script.

Comment: If the script is running 24/7 you have to show enough of those parts. If it's not, probably break out this functionality so you can call it from `cron`.

Answer (score 4):

You say that you want to run a particular function in a script, presumably without running the entire script.

This sounds like a case where you should move that functionality into a separate library. The big script could include that library. Any other tool can also use that library. That allows you to write a small program to handle the mail through cron or some other scheduler.

When I've run into these legacy situations, I've started to refactor programs so they are really libraries that magically run as scripts when you use them as scripts. These are called "modulinos", and I first described the idea in [How a script becomes a module](https://briandfoy.github.io/how-a-script-becomes-a-module/).

Once you've done that, you can much more easily test the code too.

Comment: Thanks Brian. But my outer script runs on a cron already and my team does not want to add another cron for the same job. So, I'm trying to figure if there's some way that avoids me having another cron for this logic.

Comment: That's the sort of info you should have in your original question.

Comment: I've added the info to the question now

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to send recurring emails only once on particular days, even when there's a cron running on outer script.

Posting here for helping out others. I'm using datetime objects to check the date and day to send the emails.

```
if(($dt_before <= $dt_today) and ($dt_today <= $dt_after)) {
        if(DateTime->now(time_zone =>'-0800')->day_name eq "Monday" or DateTime->now(time_zone =>'-0800')->day_name eq "Wednesday") {
            &prcFunctionCall();
        }
}
```